Using an array of length 2 or using an object to wrap two floats for high efficiency?
I am writing an app that requires high efficiency. It's an app that deals constantly with floats.
I've been told to avoid constants (static final fields).
So basically I have a method like this one:
public void dealWithFloats(float x, float y)
{
...
}

Since it's always a couple of floats I was wondering if I should use an array or an object like Point.
If I use an array it would be basically like this:
public float[] getFloats(){
float[] array = new float[2];
float[0] = getX();
float[1] = getY();
return array;
}


Why have you been told to avoid FP constants? Compilers stand a much better chance of understanding your intentions and optimising code if you give them good visibility of all of your fixed values. A float array and a struct of two floats should be indistinguishable as far as the compiler is concerned. However, allocating and deallocating them often and 2 at a time could be a non trivial overhead.

"avoid constants (static final fields)" but posted code shows none of these || BTW the compiler is able to recognize constant expressions, which can be directly inserted in compiled code (no field access, no method call, or similar) - Java Language Specification 15.29. Constant Expressions -- but beware of Premature Optimization, the Root of All Evil (Donald Knuth)

For something like this, I would put efficiency aside. It's not going to be a significant difference. Having said that, I'd continue by saying It's hard to say without knowing more about what it is you are trying to do. In some cases, it could be a matter of opinion. (And opinion based questions are not welcome here.) I prefer code that reflects the domain of the problem it attempts to solve. For working with a Cartesian plane, I might prefer to use something like Point2D.Float or Point2D.Double


I've been told to avoid constants (static final fields).

This is such a bizarre fly-by WTF statement. Why not? In context of your post, perhaps you've been told this for performance reasons: That the person who told you this wants you to write:
foo(5.5);

instead of:
private static final float FOO = 5.5;

...

foo(SOME_CONSTANT);

Because the second one needs to do a field lookup which is slow. This is completely false - the second snippet is exactly as fast as the first. Run javap to prove it - constants are inlined. This kind of knee-jerk ideas about how performance goes is exactly how not to write optimized code. You write your code 'clean' (clean meaning: Properly abstracted, easy to maintain, easy to understand, easy to test), then you write a test case that simulates expected load, then run profilers to find the hot path, and with the profiler in hand, you tweak code (which, if your code is properly written, will be easy) and rerun the profiler to see if your flailings have an effect.
Failure to operate in the above manner means you are going to fail, and badly. You can't optimize code with ideas like 'avoid constants'.

Since it's always a couple of floats I was wondering if I should use an array or an object like Point.

A new float[2] and a new Point() where Point is defined as record Point(float x, float y) have similar performance characteristics.
If you want efficiency it is plausible/likely that avoiding that and going with 2 actual floats is more efficient. This:
for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
  float x = 1.2;
  float y = 3.4;
  someMethod(x, y);
}

is considerably simpler for the system to run than:
float[] floats = new float[2];
for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
  floats[0] = 1.2;
  floats[1] = 3.4;
  someMethod(floats);
}

Because the second one has a layer of indirection (an object on heap) whereas the first one is all-stack. So, the first one is 'faster'. Except, the JVM is very good at optimizing and may well optimize the second to be just as fast. This gets us back to: use profilers and tools like JMH; performance tweaking MUST have objective numbers or it is pointless.
I'd be extremely surprises if the second one is somehow faster. That does not seem possible (but, again, profilers, you need proof for all of this stuff).

Is the JVM compiler smart enough to move loop invariants outside the for loop or will it slavishly assign 1.2 and 3.4 to x & y/floats[ ] every time?

@MartinBrown Use tools to find out. Finding out by way of asking random SO users is in breach of that whole this is not how you performance optimize. Proof / objective numbers or GTFO is the mantra thing.

@rzwitserloot Basically I was performing constantly the same arithmetic operations like for instance: someMethod(someFloat/displaySize.x, some/someFloat/displaySize.y)  since field lookup is not slow I will store the results and avoid performing the same operations.
This will obviously beneficial in terms of speed. What about memory? I suppose storing the result of 25 FP operations should be almost irrelevant.

This will obviously beneficial in terms of speed. Sigh. You're not listening. NO, THAT IS WRONG. You can't trust your instincts. I think we can conclude here they're just all wrong. All of them. A field access is fast, sure. The JVM will possibly optimize it - maybe. But a division is probably faster. Caching values is, on modern CPU architecture, often slower. You cannot just jump to the conclusion that this would be faster. TEST IT. RUN PROFILERS AND JMH.

@rzwitserloot Okay, I will test it. There is one problem though. I can test easily the speed but how would I know which one would be more beneficial for less memory consumption? I am not sure profilers would be enough to ascertain which approach would consume less memory.

@rzwitserloot I was just curious. I only ever use Java for trivial stuff.

One thing that is always true is that hardware multiplies are very much faster than divides (on time and latency) so that if you are rescaling a lot of things (like a large array) it is way better to compute 1/displaysize.x once and swap all the divisions for multplies. Many optimising compilers will do this for your with constants. However, the OP would be better served by getting the algorithm right first and then seeing if it is fast enough and looking for any bottlenecks. Premature optimisation is invariably done in the wrong place and just makes code impenetrable. and harder to maintain

@MartinBrown a JVM doesn't have one execution system. The basic system would shavishly assign those values every time; neither javac nor the basic execution line is smart in any way. The reason java is, nevertheless, generally as fast, if not faster at C as long as fancy things java can't do aren't involved, is that java has a second execution strategy: Hotspot.

@MartinBrown  Only after a bunch of code has run many times and is identified as part of the hot path will the JVM analyse the heck out of code (with the benefit of bookkeeping about how it ran, useful for e.g. branch prediction - something C compilers do not have), and produce a machine code custom optimized version. That version likely won't re-assign those constants every loop.

@zaxunobi Martin's last comment (about how at least in C land divides are rejiggered to multiplies if possible for you), and that premature optimization just makes things bad because you really don't know what to do until you know whether some optimization is being applied by the system for you or not - is absolutely correct, great advice.
